# Promise not returning first time in node js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to to make a simple API and from what I'm understood I have to use a promise, but the promise doesn't return properly. It returns the JSON from the last request, not the current one.

Here is the code I'm using. I might be going at this on a completely wrong approach, but as I'm new to JavaScript I can't tell.

````
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    My login details are here
});

//create a server object:
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    try {
        var initializePromise = get_results();
        initializePromise.then(function(result) {
            output = result;
        });

        res.write(output.toString());
    } catch (error) {
        res.write("Something went wrong")
        console.log(error);
    } finally {
        res.end();
    }
}).listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080

get_results = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        con.query(
            "SELECT * FROM Links",
            function (err, rows) {
                if (rows === undefined) {
                    reject(new Error("Error rows is undefined"));
                } else {
                    var d = new Date();
                    resolve(d.getSeconds());
                }
            }
        )
    }
    )
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to return the response in .then of initializePromise. This is the reason you are having last object in response. You just have to shift the line of res.write inside you .then.

````
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
});
//create a server object:
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
try {
    var initializePromise = get_results();
    initializePromise.then(function(result) {
        output = result;
        res.write(result.toString());
    });


} catch (error) {
    res.write("Something went wrong")
    console.log(error);
} finally {
    res.end();
}
}).listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080

get_results = function () {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    con.query(
        "SELECT * FROM Links",
        function (err, rows) {
            if (rows === undefined) {
                reject(new Error("Error rows is undefined"));
            } else {
                var d = new Date();
                resolve(d.getSeconds());
            }
        }
    )
}
)
}```
````

Hope this helps! please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Promises work asynchronously. You pass a callback to the promises `.then` that get's executed **once the promise resolves**.

In your case this means that `res.write(output.toString)` is executed **before** the promise resolves. Thus `output = result` has not yet been called.

Pull the `res.write` command into the callback and you should get the correct results.

Comment: Note: it is random that you get exactly the last result. If you were to send many requests you might get an even more outdated result.